# Why are so few questions/answers appearing in the Review section?

Tags: support

Previously, when going to the "Review" section, I was presented with a large list of questions and answers pending review.

I started noticing this weekend that the lists are much shorter, even with "All" specified for the timeframe.  Among all the categories, I only see a total of 8 posts listed.

Was a change made to this functionality, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may have been me.

I decided that it was high time that I went through the lists and checked the posts. As there weren't that many (compared to other sites) I ended up going through them all.

> [If 2 reviewers (users with Strunk & White) click on the "review question/answer" link it will vanish from the global list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113180/59303)

As I did all that I could see, there's a good chance I was the 2nd user to review them - particularly as you say you've been using /review yourself - so the system now treats them as "done".

Comment: I am a reviewaholic!